# CreateFileW with \\?\ prefix and long file name returned INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE

Tags: winapi

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    auto h = CreateFileW(
        LR"(\\?\C:\Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooog.txt)",
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        nullptr,
        CREATE_NEW,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL
    );
    assert(h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
    CloseHandle(h);
}
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Project settings btw:
[image]

Running with admin doesn't solve the issue either. I am running windows 11 22621
[image]

Comment: Your application may not have permission to WRITE to the ROOT of your C drive.  Try Running it as Administrator to see if that works (or write to a folder you DO have WRITE access to).

Comment: There is still a limit, you can't create a file or directory that can't be enumerated by FindFirstFile().  The WIN32_FIND_DATA.cFileName member restricts to MAX_PATH-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running into an NTFS (presumably) limitation, where path components (including the file name) [are limited to 255 UTF-16 code units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Structure). The file name you are supplying is 263 code units long, and you are getting an [`ERROR_INVALID_NAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) error code ("The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.").

To solve this, you'll need to make the file name part no longer than 255 UTF-16 code units.

Comment: Life saver. Also for completeness, adding that \\?\ still limits a **Directory** segment path to 255 chars.

Comment: This limitation does not apply to just NTFS, it applies to all file systems, and is clearly documented on MSDN:  [Maximum Path Length Limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation). The actual length is *usually* 255 characters, but can be queried at runtime using the `lpMaximumComponentLength` parameter of `GetVolumeInformation()`.